# Problems with a wordpress project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Im new to StackOverflow, I need help with a wordpress project, I have created a post type for projects and I am displaying the projects with a function in the projects page, I need that when a user clicks on a project that projects appears in a modal or lightbox window, the problem is that I try to pass the value using get but the web refreshes and the modal dissapears, anybody could help me please???

This is the function:

```
/*funcion para mostrar los proyectos en la pagina de proyectos  <-- jochi 17/07/2016 */
function showProyects(){
echo '<div class="row">';
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'proyectos', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page'=> 15 ) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
            <div class="pindex col-xs-12 col-md-4">

             <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <?php  $proID = get_the_ID(); ?>

                    <a href="?projectID=<?php echo $proID;?>" rel="lightbox">
                    <div class="pimage opnpop">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="pcontent">
                    <?php
                     the_content();

                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="btnproyect"><a class="opnpop" href="?projectID=<?php echo $proID;?>">Leer Más &raquo;</a></div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile;

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

echo '</div>';

}

add_shortcode('show_proyects', 'showProyects');
```

I created a shortcode to use the function in the projects page.

Comment: Please improve your code formatting, because as it stands, the code can't be read properly.

Comment: You need to add an event listener for the "opnpop" class and use `event.preventDefault()` when it's clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried adding the event.precentDefaut(); but the ID does not pass to the url :(